# Zebra css with selector (skip line)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need a zebra css over the div but not including the div with the "topic" class
Can I do that?

**Edit:**
I want every topic class will start the zebra counting from start.

```
<style>
 .msg:nth-child(odd) {  background-color: Red;}
</style>
<div class="msg topic">
<div class="msg">
<div class="msg">
<div class="msg">
<div class="msg topic">
<div class="msg">
<div class="msg">
```

**Edit 2:**
Something like this

```
<div class="msg topic">
<div class="msg class1">
<div class="msg class2">
<div class="msg class1">
<div class="msg topic">
<div class="msg class1">
<div class="msg class2">
<div class="msg class1">
<div class="msg class2">
```

Comment: Javascript I'm afraid...unless there is actually a pattern here. If the `topic `class appears at regulat intervals that is.

Comment: You can do it in CSS @Paulie_D, see my answer.

Comment: Not sure that's actually what the OP is looking for...but we'll see.

Answer (score 2):

Something like ths..?  (https://jsfiddle.net/uus62q3t/)

HTML:

```
<div class="msg topic">msg topic</div>
<div class="msg">msg</div>
<div class="msg">msg</div>
<div class="msg">msg</div>
<div class="msg topic">msg topic</div>
<div class="msg">msg</div>
<div class="msg">msg</div>
```

CSS:

```
.msg:nth-child(odd):not(.topic) {  background-color: Red;}

 .topic { background:yellow; /* just for demo */}
```

Comment: Can I do that so the topic class will start a new zebra counting?

Comment: Im unsure what you mean, can you elaborate? maybe even provide an example of your desired output, it would be ever so helpful.